# Data format and actual shape

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I'm trying to migrate TensorFlow checkpoint weights to PyTorch.

When I extract some weights with `cp.load_variable(<CKPT>, <FIELD_NAME>)`, I get a 4D list ordered as HWCN, for example [1, 1, 512, 1024] which is clearly HWCN.
However, all convolution blocks `data_format` are set to NHWC.

So, the question is, why there's mismatch?
what should I believe? does the 4D list `from cp.load_variable` is correct and all left to do is `permute` the dimensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weights are not given as *HWCN*, as the weights do not have any batch dimension (*N*), otherwise that would apply a different weight for each sample in the batch. The shape is *[kernel_height, kernel_width, in_channels, out_channels]*. There is no mismatch, because `data_format` specifies which format the input and output use.

In PyTorch the weight of convolutions is given as *[out_channels, in_channels, kernel_height, kernel_width]*, therefore you only need to permute the dimensions.